# dart clipboardData always null

Tags: dart, dart-html

The following

**main.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test" draggable="true">hello world</p> 
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <!-- for this next line to work, your pubspec.yaml file must have a dependency on 'browser' -->
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and **main.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  var elem = query('#test');
  elem.onDragStart.listen((evt) {
    evt.clipboardData.setData('text/html', elem.innerHtml);
  });
}
```

are producing the exception

```
The null object does not have a method 'setData'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'setData'
Receiver: null
Arguments: ["text/html", "hello world"]
```

I've searched, but can find no relevant information about what I could possibly be doing wrong, or about clipboardData in dart at all (even the API is silent on the issue, and the source dart:html file just points to "native code"

Comment: Just to check - is this clipboard data, or would `evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', elem.innerHtml);` work for you?

Comment: Yes, `dataTransfer` is the attribute I'm looking for. It must have changed recently -- it is still `clipboardData` in the API docs and `dataTransfer` gives me a warning in the editor, but it seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I've added a new answer which converts my comment above into an answer (and also addresses the autocomplete / editor warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From my comment to the original question)

Use this instead:

```dart
evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', elem.innerHtml);
```

It is an [attribute on `MouseEvent` (api ref)](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/MouseEvent.html#dataTransfer) rather than the base `Event` class, and you can get autocomplete and remove editor warnings by explicitly declaring that `evt` is of type `MouseEvent`:

```dart
elem.onDragStart.listen((MouseEvent evt) {
  evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', elem.innerHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`clipboardData` seems to have been deprecated without warning. In web_ui components (where I first observed this), the dataTransfer attribute is not recognised by the editor as a valid attribute on instances of `Event`. I can't find any reference on the web as to why this change was made (the API docs don't say anything on the matter and I couldn't find any recent posts on the discussion board)...